# Should we bury [Money-Making]?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, meta, burninate-request

The [money-making](/questions/tagged/money-making) tag seems to be a [meta tag](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/08/07/the-death-of-meta-tags/) - it doesn't seem useful, and just adds noise. SE's financial plans are one of the few things the average user's likely to not have a say in, and I'm sure there's better, less meta tags for it.

Is it ok to go quietly get rid of it?

Comment: 12 hours ago the Tavern was not ready for [this](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/6790562#6790562) ...

Comment: Technically, *every* tag here is a meta tag, excluding the four required ones.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Shadow Wizard's suggestion for a merge](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/308197/should-we-bury-money-making/308199#308199) seemed reasonable, so I did that: [business-model](/questions/tagged/business-model).

Note that [business](/questions/tagged/business) was used for a few other things, so I disambiguated that.

Answer (score 5):

Well, I think *some* tag is needed, we can merge [business](/questions/tagged/business) with [business-model](/questions/tagged/business-model), add proper wiki, and retag those about Stack Exchange business model with this, removing [money-making](/questions/tagged/money-making) from others.